# java_import already initialized constant

Tags: java, ruby, dependencies, jruby, dependency-management

I just started using JRuby and I create a small test file:

```
require 'java'
java_import java.io.File

f = File.new ARGV[0]
```

When I run the program like so: `jruby test.rb file.txt`
I get the following warning:

`/Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/1.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/builtin/javasupport/core_ext/object.rb:99 warning: already initialized constant File`

The class of `f` is in fact the java File class, but I still get the warning, any help??

I found out this is related to the following JRuby ticket by looking in object.rb:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-3453

Comment: Any reason to explicitly use the Java file class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like a reasonable warning to me, since Ruby already has a File class (i.e. the constant "File" was already initialized to refer to the Ruby File class).

Myself, I would probably skip the import and just do

```
require 'java'
f = java.io.File.new ARGV[0]
```

which should work and would eliminate name clashes.

You can also do

```
require 'java'
java_file = java.io.File
f = java_file.new ARGV[0]
```

or

```
module JavaIO
   include_package "java.io"
end

f = JavaIO::File.new ARGV[0]
```